# Reducing code complexity with LINQ

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have the following classes:

```
public class Shipment
{
 public int Id { get; set; }  
 public List<Line> Lines { get; set; }
}

public class Line
{
 public int Id { get; set; }  
 public List<Package> Packages { get; set; }
}

public class Package
{
 public int Id { get; set; }  
 public List<Event> Events { get; set; }
}

public class Event 
{
 //irrelevant properties
}
```

I also have a dictionary of Events and packageIds:

```
Dictionary<Event, int> packageEvents; //already populated
```

I want to match all the package events from the dictionary with their corresponding packages. The code I've written has 3 imbricated foreach statements and therefore the complexity of O(n^3). I would like to transform the code into a smaller statement using Linq and desirably also reduce the complexity.

```
foreach (var shipment in shipments)
{
    foreach (var line in shipment.Lines)
    {
        if (line.Packages.Any())
        {
            foreach (var package in line.Packages)
            {
                var eventsByPackage = packageEvents.Where(x => x.Value == package.Id).Select(x => x.Key);
                if (package.Events == null)
                {
                    package.Events = new List<Event>();
                }
                package.Events.AddRange(eventsByPackage);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any suggestion. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `if (line.Packages.Any())` is redundant and can be safely dropped

Comment: I think site https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is more proper for this question.

Comment: 3 nested loops are an indicator of `O(n^3)` (and the `AddRange(eventsByPackage)` would make it `O(n^4)`) but if the outer loops are just groupings of inner elements, then the real complexity can still be `O(n)` with `n` being the number of events to be processed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

same as Dmitry's answer but having a slightly different syntax

```
var merge = new Func<Package, Package>(package =>
{
    var found = packageEvents
        .Where(p => p.Value == package.Id)
        .Select(p => p.Key);

    if (package.Events == null)
        package.Events = new List<Event>();
    package.Events.AddRange(found);
    return package;
});

var query = from shipment in shipments
            from line in shipment.Lines
            from package in line.Packages
            select merge(package);
```

Comment: It's strange to see this being accepted. This code does **nothing**. The `query` is just definition. In order to produce result, it has to be executed by `foreach`ing it or calling `ToList()` etc. which is weird. Many people fail in that trap when trying to use LINQ for something it's not designed for (update in this case).

Comment: your're right, this is just the query definition, and as is the case with any query definition, it needs to be materialized like you mention as well, for example via ToList, i just did not include the obvious in my answer. check gist for the complete overview of the provided solution https://gist.github.com/dandohotaru/984c9cdee141cfc0c546398cf2e9adf4

Answer (score 4):

If you want *Linq* solution I suggest using `SelectMany` *twice* in order to obtain flatten `IEnumerable<Package>`:

```
var packages = shipments
  .SelectMany(shipment => shipment.Lines)
  .SelectMany(line => line.Packages);

foreach(var package in packages) {
  if (package.Events == null)
    package.Events = new List<Event>();

  package.Events.AddRange(packageEvents
    .Where(x => x.Value == package.Id)
    .Select(x => x.Key));
}
```

However, willy-nilly you have to scan all packages and that's why you *can't reduce* `O(n**3)` time complexity; all you can obtain with a help of Linq is *readability*